# Nodejs/Socketio level of SSL certificate required

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, socket.io

I want to use secure websockets with socketio and nodejs so that more of my mobile traffic/corporate networks can utilise websockets.

What level of SSL certificate is required for most browsers to accept the certificate/server as trustworthy. Browsers don't have an interface for reviewing/allowing SSL connections for websockets as far as I know, so how do they handle a cert they don't trust? Do they just refuse the connection?

What *minimum* level is required from an example list: https://www.123-reg.co.uk/ssl-certificates/ and has anyone done any research into how browsers handle various levels of SSL in websocket connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Securing a websocket is no different to securing an HTTP connection. A TLS handshake process will happen first to establish a secure connection and then an HTTP connection will be established over this secure link. For a websocket the additional step of upgrading the HTTP session to a socket will be taken. What this means is that whatever works for HTTPS will work for WSS. [This link](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/28/html5-websocket-security-is-strong/) has a useful diagram.

I'm not sure what the difference is between the "123 SSL" and "Domain SSL" levels in your link,  if the lower cert is issued against your domain it may be fine. Generally you want "Domain Level Validation" or above - it is enough to secure traffic between clients and your server. As long as the root certificate is trusted (generally the company you are buying the certificate from), browsers will accept this with no message or warning. For WSS, APIs and communicating with mobile apps this will be fine. The top level certificate (Extended Validation or EV) has the added advantage of additional security indicators in the browser (usually the green address bar or lock), great for browser sites but not of much use for pure WSS or API clients.